# Access violation while trying to read vector (C++)?

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector, access-violation

I have been having a weird error that I can't quite figure out. I have created a vector that contains pointers to a custom class I made. The vector, however, shouldn't have any elements in it given that I don't push anything. When trying to loop through it (or simply call .size()), I get an access violation. Anyone know why this could be? Here is the code for reference:

```
void UserInterfaceManager::DrawWidgets(sf::RenderWindow* l_renderWindow)
{
    std::cout << m_uiWidgets.size();
    for (sf::Int16 i = 0; i < static_cast<sf::Int16>(m_uiWidgets.size()); i++)
    {
        m_uiWidgets[i]->DisplayWidget(l_renderWindow);
    }
}
```

Declaration of uiWidgets in UserInterfaceManager.h

```
std::vector<UserInterfaceWidget*> m_uiWidgets;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you cast the size?

Comment: You say that the vector shouldn't have elements. Have you debugged/printed the size to confirm?

Comment: It crashes when I try to print the size to console...

Comment: Then the problem is not with the loop.

Comment: I'm curious why you cast the result of `.size()` to `sf::Int16` instead of just declaring `i` as a `size_t` (or you could just use a range-for instead)

Comment: Please submit a [MCVE]. The code you've shared is not enough to identify the problem.

Comment: The OP has a valid question, if you need more info ask for it, instead of down vote.

Comment: How would I need to initialise the vector? I assumed that my program wouldn't crash if my vector was empty...I'm using sf::Int16 because i am using a library that suggest using their variables for continuity across platforms. Could be that it makes no difference though or it simply isn't worth casting. Added declaration of uiwidgets maybe this helps find the problem. Please tell me if anything else could be helpful (however these are the only lines where uiWidgets is used to my knowledge)

Answer (score 0):

Okay sorry guys, it turned out to be a very silly mistake - I had a pointer problem with the UserInterfaceManager class itself, so the vector wasn't properly created at all. Apologies and thank you everyone that helped!